# Custom slider design issue

Tags: css, html, sass

I want to style a custom HTML slider `<input type="range">` which has some colored endpoints like this:

[image]

Currently I can achieve the result seen in the picture by:

```
input[type="range"] {
  &:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
    // width, height, positioning, ...
  }
  &:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background-color:green;
    ...
  }
```

Moving the handle to the beginning or end of the range it produces this:

[image]

Trying to change z-index I can only paint the colored points completely in front of the slider or behind it.

I tried also to give different z-index values to the browser-specific classes (like `::-webkit-slider-runnable-track, ::-webkit-slider-thumb`, ...) but that didn't help either.

Is it possible to paint the colored points "between" the slider rail and the handle so that the point is on top of the rail but the handle covers the point?

Comment: Can you copy paste full code so I can fix this

Comment: I created a fidle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/rnsh4wax/  Currently it is working only for chrome

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type="range"]:before{
  content:'';
  z-index: 5;
  position:absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  left:-10px;
  background-color:red;
}
input[type="range"]:after{
  content:'';
  z-index: -1;
  position:absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  right: -10px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

You can't put `:before` and `:after` elements behind the parent. So maybe if you put your `:before/:after` elements before and after the range bar with `left:-10px;` and `right: -10px;` your problem will be solved?

Comment: Thank you very much. That could indeed be an alternative solution if there is no other way. But it is not the preferred way since the colored dots are then not covered by the handle but are visible besides it when min/max is selected.

Comment: if you want really to have these elements behind the white square, you need to put  2 span before and after the range input and give us style. This can also be good..